# IDENTITY_INSERT Issue in Apache Kafka - JDBC - MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Using Apache Kafka sink connector to insert/update data from SQL Server to SQL Server getting following ERROR

> java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'table_name'
> when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:2075)

The Source Configuration

```
name=jdbc-mssql-prod-5
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
connection.url=jdbc:sqlserver:
connection.user=
connection.password=
topic.prefix= source_topic.
mode=timestamp
table.whitelist=A,B,C
timestamp.column.name=ModifiedDateTime

connection.backoff.ms=60000
connection.attempts=300

validate.non.null= false
# enter timestamp in milliseconds 
timestamp.initial= -1
```

The Sink Configuration

```
name=mysql-sink-prod-5
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics= sink_topic_a, sink_topic_b
connection.url=jdbc:sqlserver:
connection.user=
connection.password=

insert.mode=upsert
delete.enabled=true
pk.mode=record_key


errors.log.enable= true
errors.log.include.messages=true
```

In the table, primary key column and identity column are same.

Comment: The posted sink configuration appears to be targeting MySQL - how come you're asking about SQL Server?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning sorry it's my mistake while creating question , config updated.